# ArrayList Implementation in Java

Tags: java, array, collections

Can someone please evaluate my code and let me know how I can improve it?

```
public class ArrayListImplementation {

static class ListNode<T> {
    private T value;

    public ListNode(T val) {
        this.value = val;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(this.value);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

static class List<T> {
    private ListNode<T>[] node;
    private int listSize;
    private int initialCapacity;

    public List(int size) {
        node = new ListNode[size];
        initialCapacity = size;
    }

    public int size() {
        return listSize;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return listSize == 0;
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        if(index >= initialCapacity) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        return node[index].getValue();
    }

    public void add(T val) {
        if(listSize == initialCapacity) {
            System.out.println("No space to add a new list element");
            return;
        }

        ListNode<T> head = null;
        if(listSize == 0) {
            head = new ListNode<>(val);
            node[0] = head;
            listSize++;
            return;
        }

        ListNode<T> cur = new ListNode<>(val);
        node[listSize++] = cur;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[ ");
        for(int i = 0; i < initialCapacity - 1; ++i) {
            sb.append(node[i].getValue() + ", ");
        }
        sb.append(node[initialCapacity - 1].getValue() + " ]");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void clear() {
        node = new ListNode[initialCapacity];
        listSize = 0;
        return;
    }

    public boolean remove(T value) {
        boolean result = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < initialCapacity; ++i) {
            if(node[i].getValue() == value) {
                result =  remove(node[i], i);
                if(result) {
                    listSize--;
                }
            }
        }   
        return result;
    }

    private boolean remove(ListNode<T> toBeRemoved, int index) {
        if(index < 0 || index >= initialCapacity) {
            return false;
        }

        if(initialCapacity > 1) {
            int prevSize = initialCapacity;
            ListNode<T>[] copyNode = node;

            node = new ListNode[--initialCapacity];
            for(int i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
                node[i] = copyNode[i];
            }

            for(int i = index + 1; i < prevSize; ++i) {
                node[i-1] = copyNode[i];
            }
        }
        else {
            this.clear();
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>(5);
    System.out.println(list.isEmpty());
    list.add(5);
    list.add(10);
    list.add(15);
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
    System.out.println(list.get(2));
    System.out.println(list.size());
    list.add(20);
    System.out.println(list.size());
    list.add(25);
    System.out.println(list.get(4));
    System.out.println(list.remove(20));
    System.out.println(list.remove(45));
    System.out.println(list.remove(5));
    System.out.println(list.remove(25));
    System.out.println(list.remove(10));
    System.out.println(list.remove(15));
    //System.out.println(list.get(5)); //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    list.clear();
    System.out.println(list.size());
}}
```

Comment: unless you just want to start from scratch, you might consider implementing the List interface

Comment: Hey, I am learning Java, so just thought of implementing it. I have used the List Interface, but just wanted to see what I could come up with. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your `ListNode::toString()` the use of `StringBuilder` is useless overhead as you just append one single string. You could strip it down method to just this:

   ```
   public String toString() {
       if (this.value == null) { // beware of null!
           return "null";
       }
       return this.value.toString();
   }
   ```
2. In your `List::add(T)` method you should throw an `Exception` (maybe an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` with a proper message) if the list is full (`if(listSize == initialCapacity) {`) instead of writing a note to `System.out`. Otherwise the calling code of your implementation wouldn't notice the problem. See [Fail Fast Principle](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:fail_fast).
3. In your `add(T)` method, why are there two different paths for the first and the other items, when the do exactly the same?
4. Is it by intention, that you reduce the intial/maximum size of your internal array in the `remove(ListNode<T> toBeRemoved, int index)` method?

   ```
   node = new ListNode[--initialCapacity];  // << newSize = initialCapacity -1
   ```

   It seems a bit strange to me.

   - In your `remove` methods you use `initialCapacity` where you rather should use `listSize` (except from the line mentioned in 4a).
   - Within the `remove` you could reuse the `add` method. I would refactor it to something like this:

     ```
     public boolean remove(T value) {
         boolean result = false;
         for(int i = 0; i < listSize; ++i) { // note: only check elements added
             if(node[i].getValue() == value) {
                 result =  remove(node[i], i);
                 if(result) {
                     listSize--;
                 }
                 // break; // note: exit loop if you only want to remove first occurence.
             }
         }   
         return result;
     }

     private boolean remove(ListNode<T> toBeRemoved, int deleteIdx) {
         if(deleteIdx < 0 || deleteIdx >= listSize) { // note: if no element -> exit
             return false;
         }

         if(listSize > 1) { // note: listSize relevant here
             ListNode<T>[] oldNode = node;

             node = new ListNode[initialCapacity]; // note: same size here
             int sourceIdx = 0; 
             for(int targetIdx = 0; targetIdx < listSize; targetIdx++) {
                 if (targetIdx == deleteIdx) {
                     sourceIdx++; // skip deleted element
                 }
                 node[targetIdx] = oldNode[sourceIdx++];
             }
         }
         else {
             this.clear();
         }
         return true;
     }
     ```

Comment: @SandeepKumar added some more points.